# Laravel After Logging in is going to / Route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.7, laravel-authentication

This is mine LoginController

```
 protected $redirectTo;
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 1){
        $this->redirectTo=route('admin.dashboard');
    }
    else{
        $this->redirectTo=route('user.dashboard');
      }

    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

}
Here is mine web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');

Auth::routes();
```

I don't know Why after Successfully logging in its going to / route i want to send it to another route which after logging in i manually Enter the route i successfully viewed that route if i am logged in its not going to show but how can i manage after logging in route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You shouldn't put such code into controller constructor because it won't probably work.

Instead in your controller you should define custom `redirectTo` method:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
   if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 1) {
       return route('admin.dashboard');
   }

   return $this->redirectTo=route('user.dashboard'); 
}
```

This should work because in `Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RedirectsUsers.php` trait there is method:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
        return $this->redirectTo();
    }

    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```

defined that is used later in LoginController by default when user was succesfully logged.